# CROSS APPLY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help me in understanding the below query. I'm using SQL 2012.

I could not exactly understand why the XML were being used in this query and how does CROSS APPLY works, but my doubts were cleared by Steven Hibble, thanks to him.

```
(SELECT  CAST ('<B>' + REPLACE(GLO_PROD_ID, ',', '</B><B>') + '</B>' AS XML) AS P_ITEM_ID,
                U.GLO_PROD_NAME

    FROM BUNDLE_LOGIC U
 ) AS BL CROSS APPLY P_ITEM_ID.nodes ('/B') AS Split(a)
 JOIN AB_DS_GLOBAL_LOCAL_COMP T2 ON T2.GLO_PROD_ID = Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
```

Thanks.

Comment: What part(s) of it don't you understand?

Comment: More context is needed to understand what you are asking. What are you trying to do? Where did this code come from?

Comment: I don't see any terms in your SQL that can't be looked up on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query appears incomplete. There's probably a `SELECT...` before the first parenthesis.

In any case, it looks like you have a field in `BUNDLE_LOGIC` that is essentially a CSV - `GLO_PROD_ID` contains many values per row that look something like `1,2,3` or maybe `abc,def,ghi`. This code essentially splits that field into multiple rows - so that each individual value in `GLO_PROD_ID` can be `JOIN`ed to `AB_DS_GLOBAL_LOCAL_COMP`. It works like this:

1. Replace all the commas with a closing and opening XML tag ()
2. Book end the whole thing with an opening tag () at the front and a closing tag at the end (<\B>)
3. Convert that to XML
4. Use `CROSS APPLY` to use the [nodes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to separate each B to its own row
5. Use the [value method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the value (converting it to a SQL Server data type - in this case `NVARCHAR(100)`)
6. `JOIN` to `AB_DS_GLOBAL_LOCAL_COMP` on the individual `values`

Here's a mocked up example:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ([ID]        INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     , [CSVString] VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES ('val1,val2,val3,val4'), ('val1,val2,val5,val6');

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ([ValueCode]        VARCHAR(10)
                     , [ValueDescription] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES ('val1,val2,val3,val4')
     , ('val1,val2,val5,val6');

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES ('val1', 'Description 1')
     , ('val2', 'Description 2')
     , ('val3', 'Description 3')
     , ('val4', 'Description 4')
     , ('val5', 'Description 5')
     , ('val6', 'Description 6');

-- Similar to BUNDLE_LOGIC 
SELECT *
FROM @Table1;

-- Similar to AB_DS_GLOBAL_LOCAL_COMP 
SELECT *
FROM @Table2;

-- JOIN them together by splitting the CSV using XML
SELECT [tab1].[ID]
     , [tab2].[ValueCode]
    , [tab2].[ValueDescription]
FROM (SELECT [ID]
           , CAST('<B>'+REPLACE([CSVString], ',', '</B><B>')+'</B>' AS XML) AS [CSVToXML]
      FROM @Table1) [tab1]
     CROSS APPLY [CSVToXML].nodes('/B') AS [Split]([a]) 
    JOIN @Table2 [tab2]
          ON [tab2].[ValueCode] = [Split].[a].value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)');
```

P.S. You may want to consider storing each value as a row to begin with. It takes more storage space (and the code populating `BUNDLE_LOGIC` would have to be altered), but it would be easier to understand and usually quicker. If that's not an option, Jeff Moden has a great [CSV splitting function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Comment: Steven Hibble Many thanks for your detailed answer, it really helps. I also want to know why XML tag is being used in this query, we arent exporting the data into any file.

Comment: The XML tag is only used so that `node` and `value` can extract the individual values (i.e. what used to be in the comma separated list). The `<B>` tag could be any tag at all.

Comment: Thank you so much Steven. Your help on this is really appreciated. One last question for you. In the same query, I also want to join on one more table SAP_DATA. But there's no condition I can use to join(meaning there are no columns that are column. Do you know how I can do that. It just doesnt allows me.

Comment: I would use a `CROSS JOIN` [(learn more)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx). Ideally, you would then filter `SAP_DATA` in your `WHERE` clause - assuming `SAP_DATA` has more than 1 row.